# How can I defeat a Minecraft zombie that picked up my weapon and armor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on a world where I am constantly changing gamemode. I would like some tips on how to beat a zombie with netherite armour (full set) and a netherite sword. I want to avoid going into creative mode unless I am building.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Place a boat in its path as it chases you, and get it to enter the boat - caught like that it's unable to chase you. At this point you could try slashing it with anything, but that will lead to considerable wear of the good equipment. Using a piston to push a block into its head instead, will quickly suffocate the zombie and finish it off.

An alternative is to box it in, in a small area, with blocks, then access from above and bury it in sand or gravel (dropping it by placing it against the ceiling above the zombie's head). Make sure not to allow it to climb up - place two sand blocks in quick succession, not to create staircase out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

You can trap the zombie, and then use a [falling anvil](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil#Falling_anvils) to inflict quite a bit of damage. You can then finish it off with something that has sharpness or flame, or even a decent bow. You can then repair the armor. Once you have it trapped, it's just a question of how to finish it off.

Comment: You could also box it in and build an iron golem to dispose of it for you, but that requires considerably more iron, and is more likely to have you come in contact with that very dangerous sword :)

Comment: The area is only 2 blocks tall, so none of those methods will work

Comment: The anvil is ill-advised if you want to recover the helmet.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's so very _satisfying._

Answer (score 3):

If you have cheats, just use `/kill @e[type=Zombie]`. That is the quickest way to do this.

Comment: Accidentally pressing Enter too soon, though… I recommend adding the `/` last.

Comment: I would put it in a boat first, then look at it and type `/kill `. It should bring up a list of target selectors and players, with the top item being the UUID of the mob you're looking at.